# Solve $y''-2y'+y=\frac{e^x}{x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I got this question earlier in a test and we never discussed how you would go about solving such an equation. I did solve the homogeneous equation by writing the characteristic equation $\Lambda^{2}-2\Lambda+1=0$ and getting the two solutions $\Lambda_{1,2}=1$ which of course implied the general solution to the homogeneous equation is of the form $y_h=C_1e^x+C_2xe^x$ and that is where I got stuck. Since the right hand side is not of a good and easy form we learned about, I was lost. Of course, I used Wolframalpha and found the particular solution that was $y_p=xe^xln(x)$ but I still have no idea how to arrive at this solution. An exam is coming up and I would really appreciate all the help I can get. Thank you!

Comment: One possible way is the [variation of parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters#Specific_second-order_equation) with the wronskian. I didn't worked it out, so I cannot say how difficult the integrals are to evaluate!

Comment: @Fakemistake That actually did it really easily! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$y''-2y'+y=\frac{e^x}{x}$$
Multiply by $e^{-x}$:
$$y''e^{-x}-2y'e^{-x}+ye^{-x}=\frac{1}{x}$$
Rewrtite the equation as this and integrate twice:
$$(ye^{-x})''=\dfrac{1}{x}$$
First integration gives us:
$$(ye^{-x})'=\ln x +C_1$$
Then:
$$(ye^{-x})={x} \ln x - x +C_1x +C_2$$
$$y(x)=e^{x}({x} \ln x  +Cx +C_2)$$

Comment: So it won't be elementary functions, then?

Comment: Oh it's elementary because to integrate 1/x gives $\ln x +c$ functon then $\int \ln x =x \ln x -x +c$ @OscarLanzi. So it's elementary function.

Comment: I added some lines I hope it"s clear now.  @OscarLanzi

Comment: Ok, I got confused over where the $e^x$ terms were going.  +1 time!

Comment: Thats great if you got it now @OscarLanzi

Answer (score 2):

To solve $$Y''(x)-2Y'(x)+Y(x)=\frac{e^{x}}{x} ~~~~(1)$$
First solve the homogeneous part $$y''-2y'+y=0 \implies y_1(x)=e^x,y_2(x)=xe^{x}$$
Wronskian of these solution is$$ w(x)=e^x (e^x+xe^x)-xe^x e^x=e^{2x}$$ Then the method of variation of parameters gives $$Y(x)=C_1(x) y_1(x)+C_2(x) y_2(x),~~~~(2)$$
where $$C_1(x)=\int y_2(x)/ w(x) dx+D_1, C_2(x)=\int y_1(x)/ w(x) dx+D_2$$
$$C_1(x)=-\int dx+D_1=-x+D_1, C_2(x)=\int \frac{dx}{x}+D_2=\ln x+D_2~~~~(3)$$
From (2) and (3), we have
$$Y(x)=(-x+D_1)e^x+(\ln x+D_2)xe^x =D_1 e^x+D_2xe^x-xe^x+xe^x \ln x$$